# How to populate html block several times asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to make a kanban for my application. I want to populate it with a mysql table. To do so I need to repeat the following lines of code several times.

```
    <li class="drag-column drag-column-needs-review"  id="list2" runat="server">
        <span class="drag-column-header"  runat="server" id="listspan">
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label">Needs Review</asp:Label>
        </span>
        <div class="drag-options" id="options3"></div>
        <ul class="drag-inner-list" runat="server" id="list1">
        </ul>
    </li>
```

How can I do so? I am unsure what to do in aspx.cs Here is what I have tried so far.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateLists();                      
        }

        public void PopulateLists()
        {
           HtmlGenericControl li;

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                li.Attributes.Add("class", "drag-column drag-column-needs-review");
                li.InnerText = "Item" + j;
                list2.Controls.Add(li);
                li.Style.Add("background-color", "green");

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                    li.Attributes.Add("class", "drag-item");
                    li.InnerText = "Item" + i;
                    if (i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        li.Style.Add("background-color", "#ffff00");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        li.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
                    }
                    list1.Controls.Add(li);
                    list1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return ShowModalPopup()");
                }
            }
        }
```

The code above gives my a list with rows but only for the first list the other lists are not being populated.
[image: My lists]

the red arrows in images is what I want to do. Any help would be very appreciated thank you.

Comment: How does what this code produces differ from what you are trying to acheive?

Comment: I have added a picture to show you want I want to do.

Comment: check your css. unless you're telling it to float those LIs, they'll just append like that.

Comment: They are floating lists when I add lists manuely it works.